# Can an "air" dragon be bred before level 16?

Tags: dragonvale

At level 16 the air habitat opens up.  Is it possible breed an air dragon (fire & water) while at a lower level?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
No it cannot. The wiki says it is available from level 16.

source:
http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Air_Dragon

Comment: Your wrong, my sister breed it at level 15

Comment: @TommyJr.Zovich Proof it and arrange a wiki edit. And in case it is an exploit, contact the developers.